# More samples in AutoML did not yield better results

Tags: machine-learning, google-natural-language, google-cloud-automl-nl

I uploaded more samples into AutoML, but this did not yield better results. Why can I improve the model performance?

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that affect a model performance. More training data does not necessarily link to better results. Please make sure the number of training data per label matches to minimum required on the data import page. If you're not happy with the quality levels, you can go back to earlier steps to improve the quality:

- Consider adding more documents to any labels with low quality.
- You may need to add different types of documents. For example, longer or shorter documents, documents by different authors that use different wording or style.
- You can clean up labels.
- Consider removing labels altogether if you don't have enough training documents.